# input buttons next to each other, one form one new page

Tags: css, forms, button, center

I want two buttons, one submits the data, the other returns to some other page, to be centered and next to each other. I can center but not on the same line.

With the following code using 2 forms, both functions work correctly but one button is below the other.

```
<body>
   <div id='main_body'>    
   <form action='' method="post">   
        <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
        <input id ='button' type='submit' name='submit' value='Update' >
    </form>   
    <form>   
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input id ='button' type="submit" value="Home" />
    </form>   
    </div>            
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show what have you tried?

Comment: You want to add vertical centering or horizontal?

Comment: Thanks for the flex option. I haven't used that before.I really want to put the 2 input buttons in their own container independently of the the form container.

Comment: The header and links are in their own divs. The main div contains the input fields. So I need to put the Home button in the same div without disrupting the table format.

Comment: @marsheng Can you please post HTML code of all elements in the picture and I've provide you corresponding CSS? BTW is this allowed to change HTML?

Answer (score 1):

See this:
Hope it helps.

```css
main_body {
  position: relative;
}

#bt1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
}

#bt2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-top: 21px;
}
```

```html
<div id='main_body'>
  <div id="bt1">
    <form action='' method="post">
      <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
      <input id='button' type='submit' name='submit' value='Update'>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="bt2">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <input id='button' type="submit" value="Home" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to achieve desired layout. Also add margins if you want some space between items. Demo:

```css
#main_body,
#main_body > * {
  display: flex;
  /* align-items in one column */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* add horizontal centering */
  align-items: center;
}

#main_body {
  /* add vertical centering */
  justify-content: center;
}

/* optional styles, just add more offset for second form */
#main_body > form + form {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id='main_body'>
  <form action='' method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    <input id='button' type='submit' name='submit' value='Update'>
  </form>
  <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input id='button' type="submit" value="Home" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to add the JPG.   The example is a simplified version of my page.  The buttons need to appear at the bottom of  the form.

Comment: @marsheng Updated my answer to fit your needs.